# c++ 2 cin.getline after echader

Tags: c++, if-statement, cin

In this game I want the players to write their names.But the computer just accepts the firt name.What can I do?

Input:
1
Bob
Marry

Output:
Welcome to the game Bob and ,
Now the Computer chooses one of you.
The chosen one will start the game

```
    #include<cstring>
        #include<iostream>
        using namespace std;
        int main(){
        int choose;
        cin>>choose;
        if(choose==1){
            char name1[30],name2[30];
            cout<<"Hi player 1\nWhat's your name?\n";
            cin.getline(name1,30);
            cout<<"Hi player 2\nWhat's your name?\n";
            cin.getline(name2,30);
            cout<<"Welcome to the game"<<name1<<"and"<<name2<<"Now the Computer chooses one of you.The chosen one will start the game\n\n";  
}
```

Comment: can you please check it again?I forgot the cin-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I changed your code a little and it works fine.

```
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int choose;
    cin >> choose;
    if( choose == 1 ){
        string name1, name2;
        cout << "Hi player 1\nWhat's your name?\n";
        cin >> name1;
        cout << "Hi player 2\nWhat's your name?\n";
        cin >> name2;
        cout << "Welcome to the game" << name1 << "and" << name2 << "Now the Computer chooses one of you.The chosen one will start the game\n\n";
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And you don't have restrictions with name length.

Comment: Thanks a lot.you have helped me so much!Awesome!